# Using a custom claims provider to populate user properties (Email and Display Name)

Tags: user-profile, adfs, claims, claim-provider

We have a custom claims provider that calls a web service in order to provide search and resolve for users being federated from ADFS.  This web service provides names, email addresses, and AD security groups that the user belongs to.  Is it possible to modify the display name and email fields of the user profile in the user information list from within the claim provider?

Answer (score 1):

Update User Profiles via a BCS connection to the web service. The built-in timer jobs will then update the user information list.